# Python function to find out tic tac toe winner

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Code to find out tic tac toe winner**
I have written the following function to find the tictactoe winner 
The input variables are fed as a list and will be supplied in the form provided below

example:
tictactoe(["OO.","XOX","XOX"])

The function written is as follows:
I am sure this is not the most elegant way to write it and was looking for more suggestions

```
import numpy as np
def (game_result):
    a=[]
    for i in range(len(game_result)):
        for i in game_result[i]:
            print (i)
            a.append(i)
    print (a)
    myarray=np.asarray(a)
    c=myarray.reshape(3,3)
    print (c)
    c1=(c[0,0] == c[0,1] == c[0,2] != ('.'))
    c2=(c[1,0] == c[1,1] == c[1,2]!= ('.'))
    c3=(c[2,0] == c[2,1] == c[2,2] != ('.'))
    c4=(c[0,0] == c[1,0] == c[2,0]!= ('.'))
    c5=(c[0,1] == c[1,1] == c[2,1] != ('.'))
    c6=(c[0,2] == c[1,2] == c[2,2]!= ('.'))
    c7=(c[1,1] == c[2,2] == c[0,0]!= ('.')) 
    c8=(c[0,2] == c[1,1] == c[2,0]!= ('.')) 
    if (c1):
        return c[0,0]
    elif (c2) :    
        return c[1,0]
    elif (c3) :    
        return c[2,0]
    elif (c4) :    
        return c[0,0]
    elif (c5) :    
        return c[0,1]
    elif (c6) :    
        return c[0,2]
    elif (c7) :    
        return c[1,1]
    elif (c8) :    
        return c[1,1]
    else :
        return 'D'
```

Comment: Why not use a binary array?

Comment: The input way is fixed and will be supplied in the form of list string

Answer (score 0):

How about creating (static or dynamic) list of those `lines` that player needs to create to win.

Ie. something like

```
lines = [
    [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2]],
    ...
    [[0,2], [1,1], [2,0]],
]
```

and then use loop to compare values. If you find match, just pick one character from that line to get winning character.

Comparing takes then just one `if` statement, and reading winner takes one line of code.

Comment: can you write the loop and illustrate?